# Scalable Python SVM for multi-class prediction

Tags: python, scikit-learn, svm

I want to predict the probability of multi-class classification SVM in python. I am really having a hard time finding something that is scalable and gives decent results.

Two options I have are LinearSVC and SVC. 
The former works fast but yields poor probability estimates(check code below).

```
prob_pos = clf.decision_function(X_test)
prob_pos = (prob_pos - prob_pos.min()) / (prob_pos.max() - prob_pos.min())
```

Also, I can CalibratedClassifierCV but it has no option to parallelize.
While the later works very slow(fit time complexity is more than quadratic in the number of training examples) and gives decent probability estimates(Platt scaling).

I don't use Matlab right now due to some restrictions of my team.

Comment: Are you able to manually implement Platt scaling on your SVC outputs? What is the size of your data? Are you constrained to using SVM?

Comment: Thanks for reply! Close to 1.4 million training samples with 32 features. About 1/4 of that for test samples. No I am very new to ml. I had was looking for preexisting code.

Comment: I found this paper [here](http://www.csie.ntu.edu.tw/~cjlin/papers/plattprob.pdf) from the LIBSVM developers showing the pseudocode they used for Platt Scaling (at the end of the paper). It's not pre-existing code, but you might be able to try implementing the pseudocode.

Comment: and found some code [here](http://www.work.caltech.edu/~htlin/program/libsvm/doc/platt.py) that could be useful as well.